# combobox column gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to aske I have gridview with combobox template column and its fill with items .
when select index changed i need to set description value in onther cell but I couldn't get the index of the gridview row?
any help

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear which SelectedIndexChanges you are talking about, but I assume you think about the combobox SelectedIndexChanged.

Assuming you have hooked up the eventhandler on the combobox, you can use the following code to get the RowIndex inside the handler

```
protected void cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int idx = (((sender as System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow)).RowIndex;
}
```

Parent of the dropdownlist will be a DataControlField and the parent if it will be the GridRow.

This also assumes you have no other container controls inside your templatefield, as the parent.parent structure then could be different.